# Partial auto-wire Spring prototype bean with runtime determined constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor, autowired

The javadoc to `ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(...)` says

> Also applied if explicit constructor argument values are specified, matching all remaining arguments with beans from the bean factory.

but I can't get it to work. I get a `BeanCreationException`:

> Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

In this example, I have a bean with a constructor that takes Spring beans as well as a `String` and an `int` that will only be known at runtime.

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanWithRuntimeDependencies {

    public final DependencyA dependencyA;
    public final DependencyB dependencyB;
    public final String myString;
    public final int myInt;

    public BeanWithRuntimeDependencies(
            DependencyA dependencyA, DependencyB dependencyB, 
            String myString, int myInt) {
        this.dependencyA = dependencyA;
        this.dependencyB = dependencyB;
        this.myString = myString;
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

}

@Component
public class DependencyA { /* ... */ }

@Component
public class DependencyB { /* ... */ }
```

and my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PrototypeBeanConstructorsApplicationTests {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired private DependencyA dependencyA;

    @Autowired private DependencyB dependencyB;

    @Test
    public void getBeanFromContext() {
        BeanWithRuntimeDependencies bean = 
            context.getBean(BeanWithRuntimeDependencies.class, "runtime string", 10);
        assertNotNull(bean);
        assertEquals(dependencyA, bean.dependencyA);
        assertEquals(dependencyB, bean.dependencyB);
        assertEquals("runtime string", bean.myString);
        assertEquals(10, bean.myInt);
    }

}
```

The source code of `ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(...)` has a comment:

```
// Explicit arguments given -> arguments length must match exactly.
```

which seems to contradict its javadoc.

Is it possible to do this? What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good question. It's called assisted injection. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222460/is-it-possible-and-how-to-do-assisted-injection-in-spring)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, @BranislavLazic, but I was hoping to be able to do it without writing a factory or even a Configuration class.

Comment: @whistling_marmot unfortunately Spring does not allows you to pass just part of parameters to the constructor. There is just two choices: create factory method or pass all needed parameters (take a look at the last part of the answer) .

Comment: Is this reported as a BUG  to Spring's github? Javadocs says it should work like that

Answer (score 8):

Looks like it is not possible to do it the way you're doing.

Actually it is strange situation. According next snippet in `ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(...)`(*source code line #207*) Spring will not consider your constructor as candidate for invocation:

```
...    
// Explicit arguments given -> arguments length must match exactly.
if (paramTypes.length != explicitArgs.length) {
    continue;
}
```

And as you correctly noted it is really contradict to javadoc statement:

> *...matching all remaining arguments with beans from the bean factory*

But anyway implementation means that by default Spring can't resolve constructor for instantiate such beans. And you have to create factory method manually. Something like:

```
@Configuration
public class Config{

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public BeanWithRuntimeDependencies beanWithRuntimeDependencies(String myString, int myInt){
        return new BeanWithRuntimeDependencies(dependencyA(), dependencyB(), myString, myInt);
    }

    @Bean
    public DependencyA dependencyA(){
        return new dependencyA();
    }

    @Bean
    public DependencyB dependencyB(){
        return new dependencyB();
    }
}
```

Then you can get bean from context as you want to do:

```
BeanWithRuntimeDependencies bean = 
    context.getBean(BeanWithRuntimeDependencies.class, "runtime string", 10);
```

---

If you don't want to have a deal with configuration class and factory method, you can simply pass needed beans into the `context.getBean()`. Sure you have to get this beans from context:

```
BeanWithRuntimeDependencies bean = 
    context.getBean(BeanWithRuntimeDependencies.class, 
        context.getBean(DependencyA.class), 
        context.getBean(DependencyB.class),
        "runtime string", 10);
```